# Work Function - Photoelectric Effect

Tags: energy, electrons, photoelectric-effect

Does the work function of a metal take into account of the electron losing energy in the course of collisions with the metal atoms, or is it only for the electrons near/on the surface of the metal?

Comment: I think it for electron which are at surfaces.

Answer (score 0):

The work function is the minimum energy that you must supply to get any electrons out of the surface.

Answer (score 0):

As work function is the minum energy, so it does not include any other loss of energy.
If it include the energy loss due to collision then that will not remain the minimum energy.